# Why does the program close immediately after launch?

Tags: java, bots, telegram, webhooks

Please tell me why my program ends immediately after launch. It's a Java Telegram Bot running on my home PC. I created the project using Maven.

MainClass

```
public class MainClass extends TelegramWebhookBot {
    BootConfig cfg = new BootConfig();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApiContextInitializer.init();
        TelegramBotsApi telegramBotsApi = new TelegramBotsApi();
        try {
            telegramBotsApi.registerBot(new MainClass());
        } catch (TelegramApiException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public BotApiMethod onWebhookUpdateReceived(Update update) {
        if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText()) {
            SendMessage sendMessage = new SendMessage();
            sendMessage.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
            sendMessage.setText("Well, all information looks like noise until you break the code.");
            return sendMessage;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public String getBotUsername() {
        return cfg.WEBHOOK_USER;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String getBotToken() {
        return cfg.WEBHOOK_TOKEN;
    }
    @Override
    public String getBotPath() {
        return cfg.WEBHOOK_USER;
    }
    
    
}
```

BootConfig class:

```
public class BootConfig {

        public static final String WEBHOOK_TOKEN = "SECRET";
        public static final String WEBHOOK_USER = "archopobbkbot";
```

Console output:

```
Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: How are you _running_ this?